# Not work multiplication in jquery every time NaN show

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am take value from span tag and text box and multiply them but it not work properly.when i inspect browser then i sow that value coming from span tag and text box is fine but multiplication value(totalprice) showing NaN.

```
 $("#addintocart").click(function () {
        debugger;
        var productid = $("#product_id").text();
        var cartid = $("#userid").text();
        var quentity = $("#txt_quentity").val();
        var price = $("#p_price").text();
        var totalprice =(quentity * price);
        $.ajax({
            url: '/Product/AddInCart',
            type: 'GET',
            data: { cartid: cartid, productid: productid, quentity: quentity, totalprice: totalprice },
            contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
            success: function (response) {
                //your success code
                // also count total 
                alert("Success");
               // Successnotify();

                });
            },
            error: function () {
                alert("some error");
            }

        });
    })
```

Comment: use  var total = parseFloat(quantity) * parseFloat(price); or parseInt as per your requirement

Answer (score 0):

Can you check

```
var totalprice =(Number(quentity) * Number(price));
```

Answer (score 0):

You are taking price as a string with $.text().  When you multiply number with string in javascript you obtain the Value NaN. Try to cast your value with the Number() function.

Answer (score 0):

Parse them to numbers.

1. `var totalprice = parseInt(quentity) * parsefloat(price);`
2. or `var totalprice = (~~quentity) * parseFloat(price);`

Answer (score 0):

You are returning strings and need to convert them to numbers.

If you have standard numeric input, there's no difference between `parseFloat` and `Number`. When your input starts with a number and contains other characters `parseFloat` truncates the number from the string, while Number returns `NaN` (not a number):

```
parseFloat('23x'); // => 23
Number('23x'); // => NaN
```

Number also understands notation like `23e5` (which is 2300000)

One other thing is you can use a `+` and it will behave like `Number`

```
var totalprice = (Number(quentity) * Number(price));

var totalprice = (+quentity) * (+price);
```

Note both will translate '023' to octal which is 19 numeric (decimal)

Note that it is somewhat unclear if your `quentity` is quantity and if so, quantity is often an integer and thus you might consider `parseInt` for that number